# Permission Denied for a User that is part of AD

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a group created in Active Directory. This Group contains 3 users. For some strange reason one of the user within the group can't select  from specific type of SCHEMA whilst the 2 other users can select from the same schema 
I ran some test EXECUTE AS USER for the other 2 users and everything seems fine except for that one user and i get the following error:

> Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 4 The SELECT permission was denied on
>   the object '', database 'Somethng_Database', schema 'sch'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the comment by Randi Vertongen suggested, more than likely that user belongs to more than one group, one of which has explicit deny permissions on the object in question.

This query will show you which group(s) that user belongs to.

```
EXEC xp_logininfo 'DomainName\AD_User', 'all'
```

You can then look at the output for all of the results (making sure to also check for that specific user) to see if they have any deny permissions.

Comment: I have sorted it , that same user was part of another Group that has access denied. Permission precedence .